# How does this periodic signal look like?

Tags: signal-analysis, periodic

I'm very new to DSP, and I'm unsure about finding how a signal $y[n]$ would look like. The following is given:

1. Assume we have a finite support signal $x[n]$ which has the values $1, 2, 3$ for $n = 1, 2, 3$ and $0$ otherwise.
2. Now we have the periodic repetition of this signal, call it $y[n] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[n+5k]$.

To understand how the periodic signal would look like, I'd like to write down a few samples and plot them.

First, I wrote down the values of $x[n]$ like so:

| n | x[n] |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 |
| ... | ... |

Now for $y[n]$, I tried the same:

| n | y[n] |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| 0 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[0+5k] = 0$ |
| 1 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[1+5k] = 1$ |
| 2 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[2+5k] = 2$ |
| 3 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[3+5k] = 3$ |
| 4 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[4+5k] = 0$ |
| 5 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[5+5k] = 0$ |
| 6 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[6+5k] = 1$ |
| 7 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[7+5k] = 2$ |
| 8 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[8+5k] = 3$ |
| 9 | $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty x[9+5k] = 0$ |
| ... | ... |

Would the above list of samples for $y[n]$  be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would the above list of samples for y[n] be correct?

Yes

This is a standard way of turning a finite signal into a periodic signal. The $\sum$ means "infinite repetition" and $5k$ is the spacing between repetition. Since it's an infinite sum a spacing of $+5k$ gives the same result as a spacing of $-5k$ and you'll see both variants being used.

Since your signal is shorter than the spacing there is no overlap and you get just get repetitions of `[1 2 3]` with a spacing of 5.

If you want to learn a bit more, try it with $2k$ instead of $5k$ and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for validating and also the clarifications. I have a bit of a math background, but I wasn't sure if I apply this correctly. I will try to calculate energy and power of this signal, I might open a separate question for that if I get stuck.

Comment: Reading a bit more, it's relatively simple to calculate energy of $y$, which is $\infty$ and power of $y$, which is $14/5=2.8$.

Comment: sounds about right